# How to return SQL Server dates as a date object in Node.js ( mssql package)

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am trying to get SQL Server date as a date object using the npm `mssql` package. Unfortunately it returns type = object (`Orderdate` is a `datetime` object in SQL Server).

How can I easily return the date column as an actual node.js `Date` object?

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const ordersSelect = `
SELECT TOP 20
OrderDate
FROM Orders
`
let pool = await sql.connect('mssql://sa:wonton$98@TS1\\SQL2014/Artoo')
const request = pool.request()
const orders = await request.query(ordersSelect)
var orders = orders.recordset
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the Node module `mssql` cannot be configured to return SQL datetimes to Node date objects. Everything just comes back as strings inside the `recordset` object

However you could write some code to transform the data set after it has been loaded by the module. JavaScript can convert strings from the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss` (returned by SQL Server) to its own Date object, so something like

```
for (var row in orders) {
    orders[row].OrderDate = new Date(orders[row].OrderDate)
    // or
    orders[row]["OrderDate"] = new Date(orders[row]["OrderDate"])
}
```

to the end of your code sample provided would work.